# installation failure Symfony using Composer (definition has no class) (cocorico app)

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, composer-php

running installation script by `php composer.phar install`

when dependencies are getting installed, I believe some of the application code is being invoked; however, the missing definition throws an error. The stack trace does not help me to find where this missing definition is or where it is being invoked from. I understand this is an issue with dependency injection. The documentation for symfony points out how to resolve this issue: [symfony service_container autowiring working-with-interfaces](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#working-with-interfaces); however, I do not know where this is being invoked from so I don't know how to add an alias

### error

```
CheckDefinitionValidityPass.php line 69:                                                        
                                                                                                     
    The definition for "parameters" has no class. If you intend to inject this                       
    service dynamically at runtime, please mark it as synthetic=true. If this i                      
    s an abstract definition solely used by child definitions, please add abstr                      
    act=true, otherwise specify a class to get rid of this error.
```

### stack trace

```sh
Exception trace:
 () at vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php:293
 Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::executeCommand() at vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php:180
 Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets() at phar://composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:298
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->executeEventPhpScript() at phar://composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:209
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at phar://composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:81
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() at phar://composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:189
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at phar://composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:96
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript() at phar://composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:338
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar://composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/InstallCommand.php:122
 Composer\Command\InstallCommand->execute() at phar://composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:245
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:835
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:185
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:281
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:113
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://composer.phar/bin/composer:61
 require() at composer.phar:24
```

Answer (score -1):

go to your project directory and launch :

```
composer install
```